# ASP.NET connection String Error help needed

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net. Here is my issue. Please help.

I am trying to connect to my database which is also on the local machine as my asp.net project. I am using the following connection string

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source= NGEST1AND2\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");
```

I get an error under SQLEXPRESS (Unrecognised escape sequence) . I tried to rectify this error with a `\\` and then the error goes away but I get another error saying unable to connect to database.

Ay help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Gerard

Comment: You definitely need to use the \\, or you could use a string literal. But anyways, it's bad practice to put your connection string in your code. Instead, it should go in a configuration file `web.config`. That way if you need to change your database it doesn't require recompiling your app. Note that if you put it in `web.config` you don't need to escape the backslash.

Comment: Thanks the \\ worked as I had the wrong path previously. Thanks for the advise will look at adding it to the config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= NGEST1AND2\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");
```

Put `@` before your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= NGEST1AND2\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");
```

put @ in begining